# Fully cover polygon with circles of fixed radius?

Tags: qgis, polygon, algorithm, circle

I have some detailed polygons I want to cover by generating points buffered to 4km radius. How do I determine the best way (or even a decent) way of covering the polygons completely with minimal overlap and fewest circles? What would be a good place to get started?

Comment: hexbins might be a better route. example: https://medium.com/@northernjamie/making-a-hex-bin-layer-for-greater-manchester-c1d177a2476f

Comment: There are infinite number of sets of center points which meet your criteria, and a large number of ways to get there. "Best" questions are more *discussion-oriented* than our Q&A model can generally support, since there is little way to judge the definitive answer.  Actually implementing an optimal solution is probably an NP-Hard problem.

Comment: Is it probably an NP hard problem? Or definitely? And is there an approximation or decent substitute technique? There are infinite number of sets, but only one which minimizes circles placed and minimizes overlap

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing

Comment: Do you want it the way @PolyGeo suggested as representing area by touching circles, or do you mean circles must fully contain the polygon meaning intersection of polygon and circles is polygon itself? As the second case, circles are really not good shape because of lots of overlaps between.

Answer (score 2):

One method could be to generate a hexagon grid first:

[image]

Use your polygonlayer as grid extent and choose the double size of your desired buffers as horizontal and vertical spacing.

Now, depending on your desired result, remove the parts of the grids that do not intersect or entirely cover your polygon.

Then build centroids for your grid. Again, depending on your desired result, remove those which are not inside or let them be there.

At last, create buffers for the centroids.

Example result:

[image]

Comment: You need greater radius to eliminate gaps inside polygon. In general it is optimisation procedure, one need to find polygon rotation angle and potentially grid origin point which will result in minimum number of circles.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do that? What are some good ways to improve from this step?